# Get Class Name of Class Subclassing Array in TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, reflection, subclass, subclassing

I have the following class (ported from JavaScript wherein this works [prior to adding the types]) within TypeScript:

```
class A extends Array {
    private _foo: string;

    constructor(settings: any) {
        super();
        this._foo = 'foo';
    }

    get Foo() {
        return (this._foo);
    }
    set Foo(value) {
        this._foo = value;
    }
}
let test = new A({ });
test.push('1');
test.push(2);
test.push('3');

// outputs "A" in JavaScript
// outputs "Array" in TypeScript
console.log(test.constructor.name);
```

The issue is outlined at the bottom of the code snippet, I'm expecting to get the class name back from `test.constructor.name` of "A" but am instead getting "Array".  It seems like in the specific case of subclassing Array objects, TypeScript blows away the constructor name.  Is there a way to find the class name within TypeScript which doesn't rely upon `.constructor.name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you have `es5` as a target in `compilerOptions` and Typescript polyfills `class`

Have a look at generated code for [es5](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1&ts=4.4.3#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0FMAeAXBA7AJjWAnXYAntAN4CwAUNNdAA64CWAbmGtAPoBmA9twFzQIKRugDmAbkqUa0YN3RDcAV2ApuuABQQEKFAzEQBYdIQCUpaTJoQltBJtOSqV6igAWDCADouvaAF5oAHIebiCnGQBfKWdqUR1oADFeDXNyWKtcHSVcdGgNd08fUMdLamiM7RQklJYQJQQ0sqtC719uAOg6hoiaCoqQBLQhTvQEAHc4DRJoSNKKYZQvWiUINw0ggEYg%20cXl1fWAJl2EIX21jYBmHadKAHo76G4lFBWUGAAiWA-ofWgAKTALAAysBGLQUPdHs9Xi9PngCIQfn8ACqEOyg8GQihyBTcQZeEDcUQFU5LXGKFRqXBedBgAC2jXEQA) vs [ES2015](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2&ts=4.4.3#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0FMAeAXBA7AJjWAnXYAntAN4CwAUNNdAA64CWAbmGtAPoBmA9twFzQIKRugDmAbkqUa0YN3RDcAV2ApuuABQQEKFAzEQBYdIQCUpaTJoQltBJtOSqV6igAWDCADouvaAF5oAHIebiCnGQBfKWdqUR1oADFeDXNyWKtcHSVcdGgNd08fUMdLamiM7RQklJYQJQQ0sqtC719uAOg6hoiaCoqQBLQhTvQEAHc4DRJoSNKKYZQvWiUINw0ggEYg%20cXl1fWAJl2EIX21jYBmHadKAHo76G4lFBWUGAAiWA-ofWgAKTALAAysBGLQUPdHs9Xi9PngCIQfn8ACqEOyg8GQihyBTcQZeEDcUQFU5LXGKFRqXBedBgAC2jXEQA).

If you don't need to support really old browsers you can safely use a higher target than `es5`

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code in the [Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0FMAeAXBA7AJjWAnXYAntAN4CwAUNNdAA64CWAbmGtAPoBmA9twFzQIKRugDmAbkqUa0YN3RDcAV2ApuuABQQEKFAzEQBYdIQCUpaTJoQltBJtOSqV6igAWDCADouvaAF5oAHIebiCnGQBfKWdqUR1oADFeDXNyWKtcHSVcdGgNd08fUMdLamiM7RQklJYQJQQ0sqtC719uAOg6hoiaCoqQBLQhTvQEAHc4DRJoSNKKYZQvWiUINw0ggEYg+cXl1fWAJl2EIX21jYBmHadKAHo76G4lFBWUGAAiWA-ofWgAKTALAAysBGLQUPdHs9Xi9PngCIQfn8ACqEOyg8GQihyBTcQZeEDcUQbAC05IAfEEADTQPa4xQqNS4LzoMAAW0a4iAA)

And it correctly outputs "A". I suspect something else is going on, possibly with your build tools or config.

I would suggest trying to use just `tsc` to narrow down the problem. If `tsc` correctly outputs, you can then move on to any other plugins, or build steps

[image]